# Garbage collection in golang - how does it happen?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

It is known that go is garbage collected language and with a very efficient garbage collector.

How can that happen if go is compiled to machine code and has no run time environment that manages the memory deallocation?

Comment: Go does have a runtime

Answer (score 2):

A Go program is a collection of packages which are compiled and then linked together. One of these packages is `runtime` which includes the Go garbage collector.

See [Directory src/runtime/](https://golang.org/src/runtime/)